# Disable facebook video autoplay

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Currently, I'm using facebook graph API to pull information from a facebook fans page.
The information returns from the graph API might contains some video URLs whereby those videos are hosted in facebook.
So, I need to display those information in my page. Whenever there is a video link (video hosted at facebook), the video will automatically play.

I have tried to append &autoplay=0 at the back of the video link, but it didn't work.

If there anyway for me to disable the autoplay?

Comment: Instead of directly putting the facebook video link into the iframe, i have an image whereby when clicking the image, the video only show up